# c++ trouble with what parameter to send

Tags: c++, pointers, parameters

I'm currently coding on a project and I have a function that looks like this:

```
Room::addItem(Item*&); //not written by me
```

I have some trouble understanding what to send as parameter.. the "*&" mess it up for me.

I've tried the following:

```
foo.addItem(loadItem());         //Returns an Item-object
/*and*/
foo.addItem(loadItem());         //Returns an Item-pointer
```

edit: It would be nice if you explain what the "*&" means. I want to understand it next time I run in to it ;)

Comment: `*&` is a reference to a pointer to an `Item`, you should pass to it a reference to an `Item` object, i.e. `&itemObject`.

Comment: my guess is that it's a badly written code, addItem probably doesn't modify that pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `addItem` function accepts argument of type `Item*` and the pointer is passed by reference. It means that the function `addItem` can modify the pointer internally. This may also imply that the object is being reallocated or modified inside this function.

Example:

```
void pointerByValue(int* ptr)
{
   ptr = new int[10];
}


void pointerByReference(int*& ptr)
{
  ptr = new int[10];
}

void main()
{
   int* p = NULL; //A NULL pointer

   pointerByValue(p); //p is still NULL

   pointerByReference(p); //memory has now been allocated to p
}
```

Pointer By Reference are only valid in C++.

Comment: Also, because the reference is to a non-const, the pointer must be an lvalue---it cannot be the return value of a function, for example (unless the function returns an `Item*&`).

Comment: That sounds right, but why wont it accept my pointer I send to it?
in SHORT code the function looked like this when it sent pointer:

Item* loadItem([parameters]){
Item tmp = new Item([paramters]);
return &tmp;
}

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like your function is expecting a reference to a pointer.  For example, MSDN has some [sample code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1sf8shae%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) with similar syntax.

```
// Add2: Add a node to the binary tree.
//       Uses reference to pointer
int Add2( BTree*& Root, char *szToAdd ) {
   if ( Root == 0 ) {
...
```

There are various reasons why you might want to do that, but your favorite search engine should be able to help you there.  One blog entry to point you in the right direction is [here](http://markgodwin.blogspot.com/2009/08/c-reference-to-pointer.html).

Answer (score 1):

The parameter type is a reference to a pointer to an `Item`, and
what you need to pass to it is a pointer to an `Item` (i.e.
`Item*`), which must, in addition, be an lvalue (because presumably,
`Room::addItem` is going to modify the pointer).

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass pointer to function

```
Item item = loadItem()
foo.addItem(&item);
```

& means that function will use reference and will be able to change it value